# Windows 7 Mapped Network Drive Multiplying to Create Duplicates all the way to Z:

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, network-shares

A strange issue came in today from some users.  At least two Windows 7 x64 boxes that have duplicate mappings of a network drive.  The drive is not mapped with a log in script, but done manual through "Map Network Drive".  Everything has been fine for months, but all of the sudden, Explorer looks like this:

- Files (\\fileServerPath) (S:)
- Files (\\fileServerPath) (T:)
- Files (\\fileServerPath) (U:)
- Files (\\fileServerPath) (V:)
- Files (\\otherServerPath) (W:)
- Files (\\fileServerPath) (X:)
- Files (\\fileServerPath) (Y:)
- Files (\\fileServerPath) (Z:)

There are some other networks drives mixed in there that did not duplicate.  The drive is normally mapped to S:\, but it decided to make its way to Z:.

What is going on here?

I've found this and will be trying soon:

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/thread/b5647cc3-15d0-4776-bb00-a869bd8f930b

Answer (score 2):

I know this is super old, but I just had a user have a similar problem. I was able to figure out the issue and show the user how to prevent this from happening.

The user had a mapped drive to a server share: `\\servername\share = Z:\`

For some weird reason throughout the day she would end up with a `V:\`, `W:\`, `X:\`, and `Y:\` (and sometimes more) along with the `Z:\`.

After troubleshooting, trying to recreate the issue I figured out she had about 6 shortcuts to shares for other folders on the server, under the `\\servername\share` directory.

I clicked on them all and opened them, one gave me a `cannot open/find the share` type of message.  I then checked Computer and there was a `Y:\` drive.  I disconnected and tried to open the broken share.  Sure enough every time I double-clicked on the broken shared folder shortcut I would get the error and a new mapped drive letter to same location as `Z:\`.  Even right-clicking on the share, without selecting any option will create a new Mapped drive letter to the same location as the original `Z:\`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but, I was recently having a similar problem.  Windows attempts to "repair" network mapping during resolution on NT systems.  If the user has a link, that refers to the shared folder/program/etc. mapped to a different drive letter, it will map a new share and create an additional mapped drive.  Find the incorrect link and it should resolve the issue.