# User having duplicate folders populate on network drive

Tags: windows, network-shares, shared-folders, duplicate, network-drive

I have a domain user who is experiencing an issue in which folders in our "Share" drive will populate with a phantom folder, containing all of the contents of the original folder. For example:

Original Folder: PDF Drawings
Copy Folder: 33NLK1~6

The copied folders all have the same naming format of XXXXXX~X. My affected user is the only one that can see these phantom folders. If he deletes them, they immediately repopulate. As of right now, it only seems to be occurring for him on our networks "Share" drive. No reporting in root as of yet.

This is a hard one for me to research as I don't even know how to word this. The closest thing I found was something about an 8.3 file creation, however I do not know enough about that to understand how or why that could potentially be coming into play.

Any advice is appreciated. I am genuinely curious as to whats going on and am eager to understand it.

User OS: Windows 10 Pro
Server: Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Comment: Make sure all drives have been deleted.  Open a command prompt, NET USE T: /Delete for all drives T.  Now restart and let the normal drives map.  Do you still see the phantom drives. Do another NET USE to verify that you only have one drive for each folder mapped

Comment: There may be a script running on login accidentally creating the recursive folder, and the Delete command may be getting ignored.  Please edit the question to indicate the OS version on the client's workstation, and the OS on the network share server.

Comment: Sorry Christopher! I edited the question to list the OS for user and server.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the Windows Mapped Network Drive Multiplying to Create Duplicates problem reported above and elsewhere including in these links (which go as far back as 2011):
[Windows 7 Mapped Network Drive Multiplying to Create Duplicates all the way to Z:](https://superuser.com/questions/347671/windows-7-mapped-network-drive-multiplying-to-create-duplicates-all-the-way-to-z)
[network drive mounts itself multiple times (win10, synology NAS)](https://superuser.com/questions/1088802/network-drive-mounts-itself-multiple-times-win10-synology-nas)
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/1d114f2b-c00c-47f0-997a-05bf4177ad65/duplicate-mapped-drives

In my case I'm running Windows 8.1 64-bit and Office 2013.

Some have reported that shortcuts pointing to the network share but using an unmapped drive letter cause those drive letters to be assigned to the mapped share. In my case it is hyperlinks in some Word documents that were causing the problem. In one Word document which has many hyperlinks (mostly to Internet locations, but some to networked drive shares), when a hyperlink in that document is edited, Word first does a scan where in Windows Explorer the duplicate network maps using other drive letters would then appear.

I couldn't find a way to prevent this behavior (other than painstakingly find and fix all the hyperlinks in the Word document), so I created a batch file that disconnects all the unwanted mappings when they occur:

unmap.bat

```
:: To conditionally unmap all drive letters except S:
@FOR %%G IN (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z) DO @if exist %%G:\Data\Clients net use %%G: /d /y 1>NUL 2>&1
```

Where "S:" is the desired mapped network share (whose drive letter has been removed from the list) and "\Data\Clients" is a unique path at that network share.